# Numbering an ordered list <OL> like an array, with brackets around the numbers

Tags: css

I have this list:

```
<ol start="0">
  <li>Tokyo Skytree</li>
  <li>Canton Tower</li>
  <li>CN Tower</li>
  <li>Ostankino Tower</li>
  <li>Oriental Pearl Tower</li>
</ol>
```

Which shows something like this:

```
1. Tokyo Skytree
2. Canton Tower
3. CN Tower
4. Ostankino Tower
5. Oriental Pearl Tower
```

Now what I want is to have something like this:

```
[1] Tokyo Skytree
[2] Canton Tower
[3] CN Tower
[4] Ostankino Tower
[5] Oriental Pearl Tower
```

Ideally I want a 0-based array like:

```
[0] = Tokyo Skytree
[1] = Canton Tower
[2] = CN Tower
[3] = Ostankino Tower
[4] = Oriental Pearl Tower
```

I've read about [CSS Numbering Style](http://css-tricks.com/numbering-in-style/) and [CSS Lists W3C Draft](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-lists/#predefined-counters) but I cannot figure out a solution that works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
ol {
  counter-reset: o-counter -1;
  list-style-type: none;
}
ol li:before {
  content: '[' counter(o-counter) '] = ';
  counter-increment: o-counter;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/Fb3ab/2/

Keep in mind the `o-counter` (or whatever you call it) needs to be on the parent `UL`/`OL` for it to increment. And, IE7 does not support this either.

More information:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#counters
- http://css-infos.net/property/content

Comment: how can I make the counter start from 0? I added `start="0"` to the `<ol>` but that didn't work with your solution.

Comment: I found the answer: `counter-reset: o-counter -1;` Read more here: http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-counter-increment/ (in **counter-reset** section).

Comment: My apologies; I just saw your comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the counter property is CSS.

```
<ol>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
  <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
  <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
  <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
  <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
</ol>
```

```
ol { list-style: none; 
counter-reset:array;}
ol li:before {
counter-increment:array;
content:"[" counter(array) "] ";
}
```

http://codepen.io/Nunotmp/pen/duhAb