# HTML CSS listing style change

Tags: html, css

I want to use listing in my code to get the following output -

```
[1]. This is my line one
[2]. This is my line two
[3]. this is my line three, which is very very long and is not justified when used under list.
```

I used the following code. but did not work

```
<ol list-style-type: [decimal];>
<li>This is my line one</li>
<li>This is my line two</li>
<li>this is my line three, which is very very long and is not justified when used under list.</li>
</ol>
```

I am new to html and css coding.!
The problem now i face is when i use this style long sentences are not justified under a single number. Here is how it looks like now : image.ibb.co/e8Nfda/image.png how to justify my lines?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15716030/numbering-an-ordered-list-ol-like-an-array-with-brackets-around-the-numbers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numbering an ordered list <OL> like an array, with brackets around the numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15716030/numbering-an-ordered-list-ol-like-an-array-with-brackets-around-the-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated with your requirement :**

```css
ol { list-style: none; 
    counter-reset:array;}
   ol li{text-indent: -2em;}
    ol li:before {
    counter-increment:array;
    content:"[" counter(array) "]. ";
    }
```

```html
    <ol>
    <li>This is my line one This is my line one This is my line one This is my line one This is my line one This is my line one</li>
    <li>This is my line two</li>
    <li>this is my line three</li>
    </ol>
```

Comment: He wants "[1]." and not "1.".

Comment: The problem now i face is when i use this style long sentences are not justified under a single number. 
Here is how it looks like now : 
https://image.ibb.co/e8Nfda/image.png
how to justify my lines? 
BTW thanks @AbhinavP

Comment: You have to fix with your parent DIV and you can remove the 'ol padding' so it can make more long line .

Comment: @Hobo can you please provide me some examples. I am a beginner in HTML coding.

Comment: @MoinuddinShuvo  Try the update now . Is your problem the line break ? The too long line get break itself .

Comment: @Hobo Thank you for you comment. My problem is solved now, Your code worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this css [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aravt3km/)

```
ol { list-style: none; 
counter-reset:array;}
ol li:before {
counter-increment:array;
content:"[" counter(array) "] ";
}
```

Comment: The problem now i face is when i use this style long sentences are not justified under a single number. Here is how it looks like now : image.ibb.co/e8Nfda/image.png how to justify my lines?

Comment: add text-indent to li. something like `li{text-indent: -1.5em;}`